# Issue with PWA Push Notifications: Unable to Redirect to Specified URL on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I am currently facing an issue with PWA (Progressive Web App) push notifications on iOS (16.5) and would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving it.

The problem I am experiencing is that when attempting to open a specific link from the notificationclick method using clients.openWindow('/messages'), the expected redirection to the "messages" page does not occur. Instead, the PWA opens without navigating to the desired destination. I want to emphasize that this issue is unique to iOS devices.

I kindly request your expertise and insights to help me identify the cause and find a suitable solution for this problem. If you have encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve it, please share your thoughts.

Thank you in advance for your support and valuable suggestions.

tried to postMessage after clicking notification and listen into app.component.ts but it only works when app is opened in background. also tried to open absolute urls, it opens but not in PWA, it opens in safari.